# React components wait for each others to render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My restaurant order application has two main part, the `header` part (navigation bar) and the `Menu content`. When I click a `link` in the `header`, the `link` will be come active (its style change), and the `Menu content` change. The `link` is a controlled component. However, I noticed React waits for the `Menu` part then update both parts at the same time. This is not my desired behavior because when the `Menu` is big, the page stands still for a few seconds. How can I fix this behavior? I tried `React.lazy` but it doesn't seem to work

```
export default function MainPage({ cartState }: MainPageType): JSX.Element {
  const menuInfo: IPayload = useContext(MenuInfoContext);
  const { currentCategoryCode } = useContext(MenuStateContext);
  if (Object.keys(menuInfo).length === 0) return <Spinner />;
  const TopOrMenuList = currentCategoryCode === "0" ? <Top /> : <MenuList />;
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {TopOrMenuList}
    </>
  );
}
```

The link component is as bellow

```
export const CategoryButton = React.memo(function CategoryButton({
  categoryCode,
  categoryName,
  active,
}: CategoryButtonType) {
  const dispatch = useContext(DispatchContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    playSound("page");
    dispatch({ type: "currentCategoryCode", payload: categoryCode });
  };

  const className: string = active ? "active" : "";

  return (
    <div
      id={`category-btn-${categoryCode}`}
      className={className}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {categoryName}
    </div>
  );
});
```

The `Menu content` change by using key `currentCategoryCode` to get its content from `menuInfo`. `menuInfo` is passed to all components through `useContext`.

**EDIT:** I tried moving the conditional render into the return statement like suggestions but it still doesn't help

```
export default function MainPage({ cartState }: MainPageType): JSX.Element {
  const menuInfo: IPayload = useContext(MenuInfoContext);
  const { currentCategoryCode } = useContext(MenuStateContext);

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(menuInfo).length === 0 ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Header />
          {currentCategoryCode === "0" ? <Top /> : <MenuList />}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Right now, if `menuInfo` is empty, you return a `Spinner`. Maybe you mean to conditionally render part of the other `return` statement instead?

Comment: @jnpdx the `spinner` is for other purpose, the whole page only load if `menuInfo` is not empty. I add spinner to wait for API to return data, then preserve the data in `sessionStorage`, so I don't think it has anything to do with this behavior

Comment: @jnpdx I updated the question to provide more information

Comment: As @jnpdx mentioned, you are withholding all rendering of the application unless `menuInfo` is hydrated. Move that conditional to the render.

Comment: There's a Chrome extension called React Developer Tools. I suggest you install it and use it to get the reason why the component keeps re-rendering, why the component waits, and other debug info. It'll make your life so much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `setTimeout` inside `useEffect` to provide the data content for `Menu` after a few miliseconds, render an empty content initially. React will then update the `header` first